# PIC board with a webserver

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, microchip

Can anyone please suggest a small PIC board which has a web server built into it and can be programmed to handle ftp connections?

Comment: Off-topic for SO - try http://chiphacker.com ?

Comment: IMHO, asking for recommendations for embedded platforms for use in development feels on topic, as long as it is tagged appropriately. It may make sense to use CW, but again IMHO it does seem fair to award rep for knowing where to find this kind of thing in the embedded world.

Comment: That said, there is [a question there](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/any-pic-board-with-webserver) which seems like a good approximation of a match to this one. Worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

Some members of the PIC32 family, such as the [PIC32MX675F256H](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=PIC32MX675F256H-80I/PT-ND) and     [PIC32MX795F512L](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=PIC32MX795F512L-80I/BG-ND) include an integrated Ethernet interface.    An evaluation board for the PIC32MX795 is available: [DM320004](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip/DM320004/?qs=kI7nsUnms46D9Q02S%2f9mXA%3d%3d) (see picture below).

You can also add an [Ethernet controller](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=ENC28J60/SS-ND) and use Microchip's free [TCP/IP stack](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2505&param=en535724) with their PIC18, PIC24, dsPIC and PIC32 families.

[image: DM3200004]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest http://www.modtronix.com/. They have a number of expandable PIC boards including Ethernet/web-server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I stumbled onto it, maybe others will. One pretty cool project is the UConTroll. It's a PIC24 based WiFi product that has a Web interface. More info [here](http://UConTroll.com).

Comment: Try to elaborate a bit more your answer. Don't just link a website.

Comment: Microcontroller
(PIC24FJ series)
- 16 MIPS operation
- 256K FLASH
- 96K RAM
- 4 UARTS
- 9 Frequency/PWM Outputs
- 9 Pulse Capture Inputs
- 5 Timer Counters
- 9 Analog inputs
<hr/>
Wi - Fi Interface
- Industrial Grade Radio
- WEP, WPA & WPA2
- Ad Hoc & Infrastructure modes
- 802.11b/g/n Compatible
- Built-in Antenna 
<hr/>
42 Input/Output Lines
- All User Configurable
- Analog Input (9 multiplexed channels)
- Digital Inputs (41)
- Digital Outputs, Level & Pulse (42)
- PWM & Frequency Output (9)
- Serial I/O (4) <p>
- 10-Bit Analog-to-Digital Converter at 500Ksps (0-
3.3V)
-115kBPS Serial